# Восстановить содержимое файла

Tags: notepad++, восстановление, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - редактировал файл `style.css` через Notepad++. Редактор выдал ошибку и закрылся сам, после открытия файла - он оказался пустой, потерялся код в 500+ строк.

Возможно ли как-то восстановить файл?

UPD: Файл восстановил, нашел кеш в папке

```
C:\Users\{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++
```

Comment: гит использую, но не для верстки. Так уж получилось, может где-то кеш хранится в win 7? Файл сохранял постоянно

Comment: @Etki, вот да. Сколько раз даже тут приходится слышать: "зачем мне VCS дома, для себя - возиться неохота, и так сойдёт"... Или: "а нужна ли система контроля версий, если работать с XYZ?" Как будто само по себе XYZ - что-то особенное в этом смысле.

Comment: > Файл восстановил

ну и славно

Comment: А я вот потерял свой план( Код то давно весь идёт через git. А заметки по работе были в файле, который после внезапного выключения ноута заполнился null-ами :(

Answer (score 4):

1. Попробуйте поискать в путях, указанных [здесь](https://superuser.com/questions/281776/does-notepad-backup-pre-edited-files-anywhere)
2. Я понимаю, что вопрос совсем про другое, но рекомендую ознакомиться с замечательной системой git ([ссылка на мануал](http://git-scm.com/book/ru)), которая может спасти вас еще много раз (лично меня - не далее как вчера). Не думайте, что "не доросли" до такого уровня, или что это какие-то лишние знания, слишком сложно и пр. - проблема у вас уже появилась на этом уровне знаний.

---

Ответ из комментария [@Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/).

---

Еще вариант ответа: Кэш Notepad++, из которого можно восстановить утерянный файл, находится по следующему пути: C:\Users{user_name}\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++.

Comment: Плюс за гит! ))